# how to check whether usb device is mounted or not through my c application in linux

Tags: linux, yocto

i wanted to detect the USB device in Linux with my c application

im able to execute lsblk command in command line then i can see that my USB device is detecting in /dev/sda directory but how can i get to know this using my c application???

foe any help thanks in advance